# How best to test for a String for being empty or populated with just white space in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell

What is a good practice method performing the following logic?

`myFunc :: String -> Bool`

```
myFunc ""
True

myFunc "           " -- can be space or any other whitespace
True

myFunc "   some text "
False
```

I had an idea of performing a trim, then checking if `result==""`, but this seems very roundabout.

Comment: Are you only wanting to check for spaces or all whitespace?  If only spaces you could do `myFunc [] = True; myFunc str = any (/=' ') str`, but if you want to strip all whitespace properly I would recommend using the `strip` function from `Data.Text` and just use `-XOverloadedStrings`.

Comment: Yeah, any white space. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 11):

```
import Data.Char (isSpace)

myFunc :: String -> Bool
myFunc = all isSpace
```

Answer (score 5):

```
myFunc = any (/= ' ')
```

A string is a list of characters. The `any` function applies a test to every element of a list, and tells you whether any element satisfies the condition. Additionally, if the list is empty, then no element satisfies the condition. So the above function *only* returns true if there was some character that isn't whitespace.

Comment: Looks beautifully succinct, but does it account for any sort of white space? Apologies if my question was ambiguous.

Comment: @user3013086 In that case, replace `(/= ' ')` with a suitable test of your choice. I believe `Data.Char` has what you're looking for...

Comment: It doesn't. If you want to consider all whitespace chars, you can do something like `all isSpace`. You'll have to import isSpace from Data.Char first.

Comment: To elaborate on the explanation given by @fjh, you could do `myFunc = all isSpace` and get just the function you're looking for, and it even works on empty strings.